# ImageIO.write() not saving file

Tags: java, image

The absolute file path seems to be forming correctly but the file is not being written.

Code:

```
var image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(attachPageScreenshot()));
var saveDirectory = Paths.get("target", "screenshots").toAbsolutePath().toString();
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("\\").append(context.getDisplayName()).append(".png");
var filePath = saveDirectory.concat(builder.toString());
var saveFile = new File(filePath);
ImageIO.write(image, "png", saveFile);
```

Output:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\workspace\java\selenium-junit5-starter\target\screenshots\Verify Total Interest Per Annum - Deposit = 30000, Term = 2 Years.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Anything amiss?

Comment: You need "saveDirectory " to be created (say using mkdirs).  You are using "getDisplayName" and assuming that it is good for file name.  What if that happens to have ":" or ".." etc in it?

Comment: This was it. Switched to just using `sshot_<currentTimeMillis>` instead for filename. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed `Paths.get()` automatically created the directory if it did not exist.

```
var dir = new File(saveDirectory);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
ImageIO.write(image, "png", saveFile);
```

Comment: Unwarranted assumption. The method doesn't do anything beyond what is specified in the Javadoc. What if the purpose was to ensure it *didn't* exist? or was a *file?*

Comment: An oversight. Nothing to be mad about.